# How to path folder outside of projek folder in php controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

-- Images

-- Project Folder  assign in url web (ex : abc.com)

Try to access path file in Images like  "/../Images/ABC.png"  but the url in web becomes abc.com/Images  not assign folder images outside project folder.

So, can someone help how to access the folder images outside?

Comment: What's your directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a folder in codeigniter root directory.

An example: I created a folder called "assets" inside codeigniter & upload a image in this folder. Image name is photo.jpg.

Now you can use  in view.  So base_url automatically replace with your website url.

Note: Must enter your website base_url in app.php